# JSON to TableView in OS X

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

**Task**: get json from url, parse it and load to table view.

For parsing I using [json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework). For load data to table view - IB bindings through Dictionary controller.

Some code:

```
SBJsonParser* parser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
self.projects = [parser objectWithString:installResponse];
```

Model Key Path set to **title** and **description**

Json looks like this:

```
{"projects":[{"category_id":1,"date_add":"2013-01-08T01:04:35Z","description":"234324234234324","id":2,"link":null,"price":null,"source_type":null,"title":"324324"}]}
```

The error is: **this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key title**

Comment: What type of class is `projects`?

Comment: @property (retain) NSDictionary *projects;

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the issue is, but as I understand from your description, you should first

```
NSArray *arrayOfOne = self.projects[@"projects"];
```

then

```
NSDictionary *dataDict = arrayOfOne[0];
```

in this case.  Then you can get at the title key from dataDict.

```
thingIWantToLoadAStringInto.text = dataDict[@"title"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because the value of "projects" is an array with one object (a dictionary). I'm not sure what you did to get that error, but to access the dictionary with the "description" and "title" keys, you need to use objectAtIndex:0 or lastObject.

It would be more helpful if you posted the actual dictionary rather than the JSON. Also what exactly do you have bound to your dictionary controller? projects?

Comment: "projects" can contain not only one object, in most cases it will contain a lot of projects.
What do you mean by "actualy dictionary"? It creates from JSON by **json-framework**. And yes, I have bound projects to dictionary controller.

Comment: By actual dictionary, I mean the NSDictionary (I assume that's self.projects). Since that's what you're binding, it would be good to see the log of it rather than JSON.